# Where does the sequence converge pointwise? Does it converge uniformly on this domain? (example)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to learn about sequences of functions, which is a new concept to me, and I would like to have a simple example to go with what I already know from definitions.  Unfortunately the notes that I have don't give a good computational example.

Consider the sequence $(\frac{z^n}{n})$.  Find where it converges pointwise.  Determine whether it also converges uniformly on this region.

Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not hard to see that $f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{n}$ converges to $0$ for $|z|\le 1$.

For uniform convergence note

$$
\sup_{|z|\le 1} |f_n(z)-0|=\sup_{|z|\le 1} \frac{|z|^n}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\to 0
$$

As for 'non-example', consider $g_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
g_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1-nx & \text{if $x\in [0,1/n]$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Pointwise limit: $g_n(x)\to g(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if $x=0$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ but it's easy to see that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} |g_n-g|=1 \not\to 0$

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement  to the first answer given: When $|x|>1$ , let $|x|=1+y$ with $y>0.$  Then for $n\geq 2,$ use the binomial theorem: $|x|^n=(1+y)^n=1+ n y +n(n-1)y^2/2+...>n(n-1)y^2/2.$ So $|x^n/n|>(n-1)y/2,$ which goes to $\infty$ as $n\to \infty.$